# Raspberry Pi Pico W lwIP http request takes too long at altcp_connect()

Tags: c, ssl, tcp, raspberry-pi-pico, lwip

### Problem

I successfully build and run a [TLS client Example](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pico_w/wifi/tls_client) (`picow_tls_client_background` executable) from the GitHub, however a simple http GET request takes about 20 seconds. It does not actually depend on the server response: I tested server, that responds empty string at all, and server with about few kb output - no matter, it takes about 20 seconds to make a request.

As the result of debug, I understand, that 99% of the request time takes `altcp_connect`- before that, it takes several miliseconds, and after that, starting from the callback, i.e. `tls_client_connected`, it takes about millisecond until the request is made:

```
Pico turned on -- [few ms]  -- altcp_connect() -- [19 sec] -- tls_client_connected() -- [1 ms] -- I see comleted incoming request on the server
```

### Tried to solve

I made a reserch, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554408/19681078) that such behaviour, can be caused by lwIP configuration in `lwipopts.h`. It already sounds weird, because it probably should been tested by Raspberry Pi developers, who posted the code on GitHub.

So I set `#define MEMP_SANITY_CHECK 0`, set

```
#define LWIP_DEBUG 0 
#define ALTCP_MBEDTLS_DEBUG  LWIP_DBG_OFF
```

I also tried to reduce `TCP_WND` or\and `TCP_MSS`, but any signficant changes produced cmake errors, that something overflows something. However, I reduced a bit that values, without errors at building.

However, all of that actions did not change request time - it still the same.

---

I also tried (although, as I wroted, this step is passed fast) to connect to ip directly, instead of DNS resolving by hostname, and it still takes same long.